# ¿Como Mostrar Con Tkinter El Resultado De Subprocess.call?

Tags: python, tkinter

Buenas 
quisiera saber como usando **Tkinter**, puedo mostrar en pantalla el resultado del modulo `subprocess.call(["free","-m"])`.

Muchas Gracias Por Su Atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más simple es redirigir la salida estándar usando tuberias (pipelines) mediante [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE). El problema es que no es seguro hacer esto con el método `call`. En su lugar podemos usar la clase `Popen` y su método `comunicate`. Un ejemplo muy simple usando un `Text` widget para mostrar la información sería:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess as sub
import Tkinter as tk

p = sub.Popen(["free","-m"],stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()
text.insert(tk.END, output)
root.mainloop()
```

Obteniendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes parsear la información como quieras y usar otros widgets para mostrarla.

Si necesitas usar esta idea para hacer llamadas a procesos que tarden en responder o que se necesite de actualización en tiempo real necesitaras otros enfoques como redirigir la stdout a una cola (queue) para evitar que la GUI se bloquee esperando al subproceso.

**P.D:** No dices que versión de Python usas, el código es para Python 2.